# Memo Line Breaks

Tags: delphi, indy-9

I'm building a tool that sends a request besides my browser request using `TIdMappedPortTCP` from Indy 9.

I want to use string `#$d#$A` (line breaks) by writing it in memo as `%0D%0A`
but it's not working fine, as you can see in the image.

What's the correct code I should use to make this work?

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);
var
  memo:string;
begin
  memo:= Memo1.text;
  if Combobox4.text='Back' then begin
    AThread.NetData := AThread.NetData +memo  ;
    form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(AThread.NetData);
```

[image: IdMappedPortTCP request & log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdMappedPortTCP` is a multi-threaded component. The `OnExecute` event is triggered in the context of a worker thread.  You CANNOT access your `TMemo` and `TComboBox` controls directly like you have shown.  You MUST synchronize with the UI thread in order to access them safely and correctly.

Try something more like this:

```
uses
  ..., IdSync;

type
  TGetForm1BackMemoTextSync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FText: string;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    class function GetText: string;
  end;

  TAddToForm2MemoSync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FText: string;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    class procedure AddToMemo(const S: string);
  end;

procedure TGetForm1BackMemoTextSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  if Form1.ComboBox4.Text = 'Back' then
    FText := Form1.Memo1.Text;
end;

class function TGetForm1BackMemoTextSync.GetText: string;
begin
  with Create do
  try
    Synchronize;
    Result := FText;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TAddToForm2MemoSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  Form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(FText);
end;

class procedure TAddToForm2MemoSync.AddToMemo(const S: string);
begin
  with Create do
  try  
    FText := S;
    Synchronize;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

//...

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);
var
  memo: string;
begin
  memo := TGetMemoBackTextSync.GetText;
  if memo <> '' then begin
    AThread.NetData := AThread.NetData + memo;
    TAddToForm2MemoSync.AddToMemo(AThread.NetData);
  //...
end;
```

With that said, you should not be putting `%0D%0A` in the Memo text at all.  Each line in a Memo is already separated by a line break.  Reading the `Memo.Text` property returns a string where each line is separated by the value of the RTL's `sLineBreak` constant (which is defined as `#13#10` on Windows).  So just omit `%0D%0A` from your text and type in natural line breaks instead, and let the RTL handle the rest for you.

If you absolutely must keep `%0D%0A` in the text, you will have to strip off the native line breaks and then convert `%0D%0A` into native line breaks manually, eg:

```
procedure TGetForm1BackMemoTextSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  if Form1.ComboBox4.Text = 'Back' then
  begin
    FText := StringReplace(Form1.Memo1.Text, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
    FText := StringReplace(FText, '%0D%0A', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
  end;
end;
```